# App not being started on device

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to play with NativeScript to create any simple android app. I've done step 1 from NativeScript's 'Getting Started' (setting up my osx environment) and right now, i have a barebones NativeScript app created with `tns create` and android platform added to it.

When running `tns run android` everything goes well and the final message before device debug logs (i'm not an android/ios/mobile dev so i assume that it's just some kind of debug log of what's going on connected device) is:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL 
Total time: 11 seconds 
Project successfully built 
Using /Volumes/HDD/Users/michal/Workspace/Sandbox/tns_hello_world/platforms/android/bin/tns_hello_worl    d-debug.apk 
Successfully deployed on device with identifier '00099fbd72369f'
```

However, there is nothing going on my device after that. No app is being launched, no error message. Just completely nothing.

My setup is:

- OSX 10.9.5
- Java 1.8.0_45
- Samsung GT-I9100
- Android 4.1.2

Have you any idea what am i possibly doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your android device is not supported by NativeScript. Use device with Android 4.2 (API level 17) or newer. You can also try it on emulator.

Comment: i'm getting the same issue and im running on genymotion Nexus 5x API level 23. Dont know the reason any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jan 2019
I verified in Android 8.1, it works fine.

First look, it looks like not working.

However, after changing the text "Play with NativeScript!" to "Hello world" in `home.component.html`, I could see the text. *The homepage message ideally should say this.*